# How to successfully detect when two moving labels touch each other in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Here is my current detection code, but it simply doesn't work.

```
def collDetect(xE, yE):
        global a, b
        if xE in range(a - 20, a + 20) and yE in range(b - 20, b + 20):
            uLose = Label(bg = "red", text = "YOU LOSE", font = "comic 48", fg = "black")
            uLose.place(x = 35, y = 100)
            mover.place_forget()
            ball.place_forget()
            return False
```

`xE` and `yE` are the x and y co-ordinates for the enemy label that you are supposed to avoid and `a` and `b` are the x and y for the player's label.

This function runs every time the movement subroutine for the enemy label loops.

I have tried a few different methods for this detection and I am beginning to suspect that it is just a limitation of tkinter, although I am probably wrong. 
What is wrong here? Is it my code, or is tkinter not quick enough to calculate it in time?

Comment: Would it be possible to have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Use a canvas, it's much better to manage than placing.